# How to merge several shapefiles with the same geometries and same attribute names?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, batch

I have data from several runs of a numerical modeling tool. The data always has the same structure - e.g. fixed set of rectangular vector tiles - no matter if there is a "valid" output or zero.

It looks like this (I only put some random data inside):

[image: polygon data in QGIS]

The attributes also always have the same names - "cell", "value" and "maximum" where "cell" is ID of particular vector tile:

[image]

I am probably going to have several tens or hundreds of such datasets and I was asked if it is possible to join them into one vector layer with several attribute columns for each model run.

The ways to merge shapefiles do not expect same geometries so I would probably end with unnecessary overlapping tiles... while the vector tiles remain the same and only the attribute values change.

I would probably be able to put together some CLI linux script first converting all the DBF files to CSV and somehow rename the column names based on the filename to avoid conflicts and finally join it with the geometries - in QGIS, maybe or some sort of geodatabase...

Or is there any better way to do this?

PS: can share some testing data if it helps

Comment: I'm puzzled when you say "... with several attribute columns..."  Could you be more specific?  How many is several?  What data would you expect in those columns?

Comment: @StuSmith that instead of having let s say 100 shp files - all with the same tiles, but different numbers in "value" attribute column I would have one shp (or gpkg) file with the tiles and 100 attribute columns like "value1", "value2" etc. taken from the input shp files.

Comment: Will the output vector layers all have the same *exact* geometry?

Comment: How do you id each model run?

Comment: @StuSmith yeah for the "same" scenario (same source and area in various conditions, time etc.) the model uses same geometry. It also somehow numbers the output files.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you find a way to convert dbf to csv (this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29529740/convert-dbf-to-csv) shows how to do it from the command line using LibreOffice), you could then use the Linux *join* command from a script to merge one file at a time. You would use something like *sed* to deal with renaming the column headings. You could then do a join in Qgis to reconnect the data to the geometry. (Or to be really crufty, convert the final merged csv back to a dbf with the same name as one of your input files.)